# JINJA (dbt) Is it possible to make a new table with several rows based on items within a single column separated by a symbol?

Tags: google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

I have a table with the following data structure:

| ID | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blue,red,green |
| 2 | white,blue |

I would like to convert this to a new table with the following structure:

| ID | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blue |
| 1 | red |
| 1 | green |
| 2 | white |
| 2 | blue |

Is this possible to do within dbt, using JINJA (or some other method)? My DWH is fully hosted within Google BigQuery and connected to dbt.

Comment: There are tons of answers on this here on SO. just do a little search! meantime, just use `unnest(split(Tag))`

Answer (score 0):

Please see Mikhail's comment for the simple, directly BQ way of doing this operation if that's all you need.

However, a more dbt generalized (`jinja-sql`) version of doing this such as when you know in advance you will eventually have to migrate a project from one SQL syntax to another (I had to do `PL/pgSQL` to Bigquery's `Standard-SQL`) could use database agnostic functions from the [dbt-utils](https://hub.getdbt.com/) package like:

- [split_part](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#split_part-source)
- [pivot](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#pivot-source) / [unpivot](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#unpivot-source)
- [get_column_values](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#get_column_values-source)

A code sample which uses these functions could look something like:

`split.sql`

```
with source as (
    select ID,Tag from {{ ref('idtag') }}
), split as (
    select 
        s."ID",
        {{ dbt_utils.split_part( s."Tag" , "','", '1') }} as Tag_1,
        {{ dbt_utils.split_part( s."Tag" , "','", '2') }} as Tag_2,
        {{ dbt_utils.split_part( s."Tag" , "','", '3') }} as Tag_3
    from source s
)

select ID, Tag_1, Tag_2, Tag_3 from split
```

`unpivot.sql`

```
with unpivot as (
    {{ dbt_utils.unpivot(ref('split'), cast_to='varchar', exclude=['ID']) }}
)

select "ID", "value" as split_tags
from unpivot
where "value" is not null
group by 1,2
```

Which for some reason, the split_part isn't working correctly on my local dbt installation right now but I hope you find some value in the intent.